# CSS to target text, headers, blockquotes, after/before images

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In my WordPress single.php I have images, text, headers and blockquotes mixed together. I want to be able to apply specific css to each based on their location to the images.

Problem is I have no control over if a blockquote will follow an image, or an h1, or just a regular p tag. For example I don't want to increase the top margin of p tags if there is a h1 tag first after the image, but I do if there isn't an h1 tag, etc.

html

```
<div id="single-pg" class="row">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

css

I tried JavaScript to wrap text in a container class to no avail, so I'm trying something along the lines of

```
#single-pg p { padding:0 20px; }
#single-pg p + img{ margin-top:30px }
```

Comment: so, what is the result of your current trying? what is the question?

Comment: A combination of CSS selectors might work but that's just a guess without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: Result is that it targets the p tag after the image. But if there is an h1 tag after the image it will still put the extra padding on, since the p tag is after the image too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option can be trying to target all p tags that are after an image... like the exmaple...

```css
#single-pg p{padding:0 20px; margin-top:0;}

#single-pg img + p{ margin-top:30px; background:red;}


#single-pg img + h1{ background:blue;}

#single-pg img + blockquote{ background:orange;}
```

```html
<div id="single-pg">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <h1>h1</h1>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>

<div id="single-pg">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, well all the text will be after an image (each page starts with an image. Will that same technique work with h1 tags and blockquote tags?

Comment: Yes, will match h1 and blockquote.... you have to add its class like the example updated